# How to include current date when logging exceptions to a file with FileOutputStream?

Tags: java, exception, logging, io

I have implemented a method to write logs to a file. It works correctly. Now I want to figure out if there is a way to include a current date/time like (`new java.util.Date().toString()`) to the logged exception?

```
 private static void writeLogToFile(Exception e) {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(LOG_FILE, true);
             PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(fos)) {
             e.printStackTrace(printStream);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

currently logging exceptions this way:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
            writeLogToFile(e);
        }
```

I know about logging frameworks and intentionally not using them in this case.

Comment: Why did you intentionally write a poor logger yourself? What's the advantage?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm just learning, sorry. No reason to down-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). It provides the functionality you need! (Date to String)

---

Another thing I see in your code is: You open the `FileOutputStream` everytime you write a log.

It would be better to keep the stream in a global variable instead of opening/closing it everytime you log something

---

The result may look somewhat like this:

```
// open/close the stream in some kind of static init()/deinit() method
private static PrintStream logStream;
private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss: ");

private static void writeLogToFile(Exception e) {
    logStream.println(sdf.format(new Date()) + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace(logStream);
}
```

Comment: I've added some small exemplary code (which you'll have to adapt for your needs of course)

Comment: Thanks it really helped me to understand it better.

Comment: Anytime! But please don't forget to close the stream if your program is done!